# JSF - dynamic 'name' attribute in ui:insert

Tags: jsf

In the code below, after logging in, ui:include is OK (changing), outputText is OK (changing), and ui:insert is not changing.

template.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" (...) >
  <h:head></h:head>
  <h:body>
    <p:panel header="LoginForm" >
      <ui:insert name="#{userBean.loggedIn?'logoutForm':'loginForm'}" />
      <ui:include src="#{userBean.loggedIn?'incA.xhtml':'incB.xhtml'}" /> 
      <h:outputText value="#{userBean.loggedIn?'print logoutForm':'print loginForm'}" />
    </p:panel>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

index.xhtml:

```
<ui:composition template="template.xhtml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" (...) >
  <ui:define name="loginForm">
    <h:form >
      <p:inputText id="usernameInput" value="#{credentialsBean.username}" />
      <p:password id="passwordInput" value="#{credentialsBean.password}"  /> 
      <p:commandButton value="Log in" action="#{loginBean.actionLogin}" ajax="false" type="submit" />
    </h:form>
  </ui:define>
  <ui:define name="logoutForm" >
    <h:form >
      <p:commandButton value="Logout" type="submit" action="#{loginBean.actionLogout}" ajax="false" /> 
    </h:form>
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Is it normal behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ui:insert's name property is evaluated in the build JSF tree phase. Use ui:include instead ui:insert to be happy.